# xslt variables value

Tags: xslt

I have this piece of code:

```
        <xsl:variable name="varPriceDate">
          <xsl:call-template name="lookup_MarketGNLPricesFile_Valor">
            <xsl:with-param name="PARAM_Key" select="'A'"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="priceDate">
          <xsl:value-of select="Col[$varPriceDate]"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:variable name="varPrice">
          <xsl:call-template name="lookup_MarketGNLPricesFile_Valor">
            <xsl:with-param name="PARAM_Key" select="'B'"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="price">
          <xsl:value-of select="Col[$varPrice]"/>
        </xsl:element>
```

Where `<xsl:value-of select="Col[$varPriceDate]"/>` is showing the same result as `<xsl:value-of select="Col[$varPrice]"/>`.
Can you help me? I need to solution it

Comment: Show us some context, we really need to see the return type and value of those templates that are called. You might want something like `Col[position() = $var]` instead of what you have but that is a guess, show us the necessary details and we can help without guessing.

Answer (score 1):

The values of both variables are result tree fragments (in XSLT 2.0, document nodes), and the effective boolean value of a result tree fragment is always true. Therefore the expressions `Col[$varPriceDate]` and `Col[$varPrice]` are both equivalent to simply writing `Col`.

To correct this we need to know what the code was intended to achieve, which isn't clear.